# How duality follows from a six functor formalism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

For the sake of this question, we'll model a six functor formalism in the following way. Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a category *of spaces* (be it the category of schemes, or topological spaces) and consider a triangulated closed symmetric monoidal category $\mathsf{D}(X)$, with identity $\mathscr{O}_X$, for each $X\in\mathsf{C}$.

Given a morphism $f:X\to Y$ in $\mathsf{C}$, we have functors $f_*,f_!:\mathsf{D}(X)\leftrightarrows \mathsf{D}(Y):f^*,f^!$ such that $f^*\dashv f_*$, $f_!\dashv f^!$, and $f^*$ is strong symmetric monoidal.

If we also suppose that $\mathsf{C}$ has a final object $S$, it is natural to define cohomology and cohomology with compact support to be
$$H^i(X,M):=\hom_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(\mathscr{O}_S,p_*M[i])\qquad\text{and}\qquad H_c^i(X,M):=\hom_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(\mathscr{O}_S,p_!M[i]),$$
where $p:X\to S$ is the natural morphism. If $\mathsf{C}$ is the category of ringed spaces (or even of ringed sites, I think), this coincides with the usual definitions.

**I wonder then how could we obtain some sort of duality isomorphism similar to Poincaré and Serre duality.** Perhaps we could begin with
$$\operatorname{Ext}^i(M,p^!\mathscr{O}_S)=\hom_{\mathsf{D}(X)}(M,p^!\mathscr{O}_S[i])=\hom_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(p_!M[-i],\mathscr{O}_S)$$
and the latter should be something like $H^{-i}_c(X,M)^\vee$, but I'm not sure how to make this precise.

Comment: Have you looked at https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01999? (Grothendieck-Neeman duality and the Wirthmüller isomorphism, by Balmer, Dell'Ambroglio and Sanders).  I haven't thought closely enough to decide whether this answers your question, but it certainly involves related ideas.

Comment: @NeilStrickland, I did! Actually, the approach I'm using is basically the one by Fausk-Hu-May, which was then continued by the paper you cited (but only in the Grothendieck duality context, which is not the only one that interests me).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your description of the six functors does not mention any relations between the $!$-functors and the $*$-functors or the tensor product, which is where these dualities are hiding.

Poincaré duality is a relation between the $*$-functors and the $!$-functors. Typically there are canonical isomorphisms $f_!=f_*$ when $f$ is proper and $f^!=f^*[d]$ when $f$ is nice (e.g. smooth) of relative dimension $d$. Depending on how the $!$-functors are constructed, one of these isomorphisms will hold by definition but the other one will be nontrivial to prove. When $f:X\to S$ is nice, we get isomorphisms (where $1_S$ is the unit object in $D(S)$)
$$
H^n(X,M) := \mathrm{hom}(1_S, f_*f^*(M)[n]) = \mathrm{hom}(1_S,f_*f^!(M)[n-d])=:H_{d-n}^\mathrm{BM}(X,M)
$$
and
$$
H^n_c(X,M):= \mathrm{hom}(1_S, f_!f^*(M)[n]) = \mathrm{hom}(1_S,f_!f^!(M)[n-d])=:H_{d-n}(X,M),
$$
On the other hand, there are vertical identifications when $f$ is proper.

Serre duality uses a relation between the $!$-functors and the tensor product. Namely, for $f:X\to S$, the functor $f_!$ is $D(S)$-linear; in particular we have the projection formula $f_!(A\otimes f^*(B))= f_!(A)\otimes B$. By adjunction this implies the isomorphism
$$
f_*\mathrm{Hom}(A, f^!(B)) = \mathrm{Hom}(f_!(A),B).
$$
One gets Serre duality when $f$ is proper (so $f_!=f_*$) and $B=1_S$ (so $f^!(B)$ is the "dualizing sheaf"). Combining the projection formula with Poincaré duality we can also deduce that $f_*$ preserves $\otimes$-dualizable objects when $f$ is both proper and nice, which gives a perfect pairing. But the usual formulation of Serre duality in terms of cohomology is specific to the derived category of quasi-coherent sheaves when $S=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ is a field (note that in the quasi-coherent case the adjunction $(f_!,f^!)$ only exists when $f$ is proper).

There are further duality statements, such as Verdier duality, which says that $\mathrm{Hom}(-,f^!(1_S))$ is an equivalence of a certain subcategory $D_c(X)\subset D(X)$ of "constructible"/"coherent" objects with its opposite. But unlike the previous two, this statement does not directly follow from the various relations between the six functors.

Comment: Dear @MarcHoyois, while I indeed supposed a relation between $f^*$ and the tensor product (namely, the fact that $f^*$ is strong symmetric monoidal), I forgot to say that I accept the projection formula as well.

Comment: That being said, I'm not sure I understand your definitions of cohomology and compactly supported cohomology (which differ from mine's). In your definition, $M$ has to be an object of $\mathsf{D}(S)$, while in mine's it's an object of $\mathsf{D}(X)$. Does that mean that homology only works with constant coefficients? If so, can't we obtain an isomorphism between cohomology and the dual of compactly supported cohomology as in Poincaré duality in de Rham cohomology?

Comment: A sidenote: $f^!$ is a twisted shift of $f^*$ when $f$ is nice, especially when you talk about the coherent/Serre duality.

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, homology only makes sense with constant coefficients. The six functor formalism can give you dualities in $D(S)$ but it cannot say anything about the dual of an actual (co)homology group...

Comment: @MarcHoyois Not even if we consider $\hom_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(\underline{\hom}_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(\mathscr{O}_S,p_*M[i]),\mathscr{O}_S)$ to be the dual of $H^i(X,M)$? This seems very natural for me, since in most (all?) cases $\mathsf{D}(S)$ is the derived category of $\Gamma(S,\mathscr{O}_S)$-modules.

Comment: @Gabriel This is what I mean by a duality in $D(S)$. For example $f_*f^!(1)$ is always the [not necessarily strong] dual to $f_!f^*(1)$ in $D(S)$ (this follows directly from the projection formula). I do not know any case where $D(S)$ is the derived category of $\Gamma(S,\mathcal O_S)$-modules. There is the case where $D(S)$ is the quasi-coherent derived category of $S$, but as I mentioned in the answer, this does not actually have all the six functors.

Comment: Well, if $S$ is a point, then the category of sheaves of $\mathscr{O}_S$-modules is equivalent to the category of $\Gamma(S,\mathscr{O}_S)$-modules, isn't it? Then $\underline{\hom}_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(\mathscr{O}_S,p_*M[i])$ should be the cohomology of $M$ but seen as an $\Gamma(S,\mathscr{O}_S)$-module, instead of just an abelian group.

Comment: @MarcHoyois I know it's been a while since you made this answer, but do you think you could spell out "When $f : X \rightarrow S$ is nice"? Are the following two equations meant to apply in the case where $f$ is smooth of relative dimension $d$, or when $f$ is proper? Also, what does "vertical identifications" entail?

Comment: @KindBubble They apply when $f$ is smooth. When $f$ is proper you have instead $H^n=H^n_c$ and $H^{BM}_n=H_n$.

Answer (score 1):

@MarcHoyois It would help to have a further comparison between $\mathrm{hom}(1_S, f_!f^!M[m])$ and a naive definition of homology such as $H^{m}(X, M)^\lor$ in the case of field coefficients.